# rm -rf : is there an all or nothing (atomic) approach?

Tags: permissions, rm, chmod

Let's say I have the following structure :

```
$ mkdir d1
$ mkdir d1/d2
$ touch d1/f1
$ touch d1/d2/f2

$ chmod u-w d1/d2
```

If I try to remove `d1`, I can't because I don't have write permissions on `d1/d2`. But it still deletes `d1/f1` :

```
$ rm -rf d1
rm: cannot remove 'd1/d2/f2': Permission denied

$ ls d1
d2          # f1 has been deleted
```

Is there a way to implement an atomic `rm` tool? E.g., if it can not delete everything, then it deletes nothing at all.

Comment: The words "atomic" and "transactional" come to mind.

Comment: Exactly. Question is : is there something like that already implemented in Linux ?

Comment: Not on a usual filesystem, not _properly_. There's no way to lock the directory tree so that another process can't change the permissions while `rm` is going through the tree to delete the files. Of course if you know no other process will come mess you up, you could scan through the tree to check the permissions beforehand. (something like `find . -type d \! -perm -0300` would check for directories where the user's `w` or `x` bits aren't set.)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. So, basically the solution is to write my own delete script, checking all permissions before deleting (or not) the folder.

Comment: We are starting to discuss many alternatives with various pros and cons. However, we have not agreed on what we are trying to achieve. What is the use-case?, what is the success criteria?, what is the problem that we are trying to solve? Edit question to make this clear.

Comment: There's always the option of trying it in a btrfs snapshot, zfs clone, lvm snapthot first if using those technologies.

Comment: @Stéphane : Can Btrfs/ZFS/LVM take a snapshot of a specific directory only ? I thought that snapshots covered a whole volume (I'm not an expert on the subject, though).

Comment: @ChennyStar, yes they snapshot a whole volume / subvol / dataset, but the idea would be to try the deletion in that snapshotted volume.

Comment: @Stéphane : So the idea would be to snapshot the volume, try the deletion, and if it doesn't work then restore the snapshot ? This could cause some data loss if some other modifications occurred on the volume after the snapshot has been taken.

Comment: @ChennyStar, no, just destroy the snapshot in any case. The snapshot being only used to check whether the directory and its contents can be deleted at all.

Comment: OK, I get it. Yep, that's another approach...

Answer (score 2):

I would write this program in such a way that it creates a hard-linked backup of the tree. Then if the operation fails, it restores the already deleted files from the backup. If the operation succeeds, it removes the hard-linked backup.

Of course, this is only logically atomic, not in the sense of "we can pull the power cord at any time" atomic; though that can be arranged too, with extra logic, and some hook that is run on boot-up.

Making two passes (one pass to check permissions, and the other pass to delete) is tricky. The logic has to be exhaustive to check all permissions, including extended attributes. For instance, if we do `sudo chattr +i file` , then `file` becomes unremovable, even though the regular Unix permissions look good: the directory is writable. The best litmus test for "can we delete this file" is to actually try it.

Here is a somewhat tested prototype of the concept, as a proof of concept, using `rsync` for the hard-link-based backup, restore. This script is called `atomic-rm.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

if [ $# -ne 1 ] ; then
  echo "specify directory to remove"
  exit 1
fi

ar_src=$(realpath "$1")
ar_tmp=$(mktemp -d "$(dirname "$ar_src")/tmp-XXXXXX")

if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
  echo "unable to create temporary directory"
  exit 1
fi

cleanup()
{
  find "$ar_tmp" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod +w

  if ! rm -rf "$ar_tmp" ; then
    echo "removal of temporary directory $ar_tmp failed"
    exit 2 # 2 indicates dirty failure
  fi
}

trap cleanup EXIT

if ! rsync -ar --link-dest="$ar_src" "$ar_src"/ "$ar_tmp"/ ; then
  echo "unable to create hard-linked backup of $ar_src in $ar_tmp"
  exit 1
fi

if ! rm -rf "$ar_src" ; then
  if ! rsync -ar --link-dest="$ar_tmp" "$ar_tmp"/ "$ar_src"/ ; then
    echo "removal of $ar_src failed; unfortunately, so did the rollback"
    exit 2 # 2 indicates dirty failure
  fi
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

With some additional effort, it could deposit some information somewhere which a boot-time recovery script could use to clean up loose temporary directories. The temporary directory is created as a sibling of the to-be-deleted directory in order to ensure that they are on the same filesystem; we cannot use `/tmp`.

If the removal fails and rollback is performed, it will not absolutely restore the exact state of the tree, because directories were messed with, and so their modification time stamps are altered.

Note that in `cleanup`, we have to make a `find` pass over the directories to make them writable. The reason is that if a removal fails because a directory isn't writable, it will likewise fail the same way in the back-up copy,  because `rsync` will have replicated those directory permissions.

Comment: If the tree is not too big (and disk space is not an issue), an alternative could be to copy the tree before trying to delete it (see my answer below, inspired from your script). Advantage : the original tree remains untouched if it can not be deleted.

Comment: See also `pax -rwlpe` for a POSIX way to make a hardlinked copy of a directory.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1

One approach is to move the tree to a `trash` directory, then use `rm` to garbage-collect. The files are removed using `mv`, then deletion is triggered by `rm` (`rm` does not delete, it only removed directory entries. Deletion happens by a reference counting garbage-collector).

E.G.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
directory_tree_to_remove="$1"
#only works if trash directory is on same file-system (no checks done),
#  if not a very expensive copy will be done, followed by an `rm`
#  :todo: add checks
#uses gnu `mv`: uses safety feature
#does not do full input error checking

trash_dir="…/trash"

#Atomicly remove tree or file, form its current location
mv -t "$trash_dir" "$directory_tree_to_remove"

#Garbage collect 
rm -rf "${trash_dir}/${directory_tree_to_remove}" || echo "error: could not garbage collect. There may be garbage left in "$trash_dir"
```

## Option 2

There may be transactional file-systems, that are suited to what you are doing.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand your option 1

Comment: as for option 2 : I believe the word "transactional" in a FS-context has a different meaning (check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/zfsover-2/ : "ZFS is a transactional file system, which means that the file system state is always consistent on disk.").

Comment: @ChennyStar it is the same meaning, but used in a different context. A transactional/journaling  FS ensures that atomic operations are atomic (even if there is a power failure, and some other situations). They don't make `rm -r` atomic, because the kernel does not consider it to be atomic (there are multiple sys-calls). There may be other types of transactional-FS, that allow atomic recursive remove.

Comment: @ChennyStar I added an example for option 1. Tell me if it helps.

Comment: I tried your example, but I don't see the point. At the end the original tree is lost (because you moved it to `trash_dir`), and the trashed tree lacks `f1`, that has been deleted. I don't see the point of your script. I'm looking for a result like Kaz's solution, where in the end I get my original tree back if it can not be deleted atomically

Answer (score 1):

Here, trying to answer the question:  "how to know in advance if a directory and the whole of its contents can be deleted".

The things that can prevent a file from being deleted by a regular user on Linux (and that I can think of):

- a non-empty directory cannot be deleted, so obviously the files within have to be deleted first
- You can't delete a file (unlink it from its parent directory) if you don't have write access or search access to the directory.
- You can't unlink a file from a directory that has the `t` bit set if you own neither the file nor the directory.
- You can't delete a file if it or the directory it's link to has the `a` (`FS_APPEND_FL`) or `i` (`FS_IMMUTABLE_FL`) flag.
- you can't delete a file if it's a mount point nor `/` nor `.` nor `..`.
- you can't delete a file if you don't know it's there. Like when it's a directory you have write and search access to but not read permission.
- you can't delete a file if on a read-only filesystem
- things like `apparmor`, `selinux` and other mandatory access control frameworks may get in the way, as well as things like user namespaces, uid namespaces...
- Any file system driver may add its own constraints. For instance, some like `zfs` or `nfs` have special files/dirs that can't be removed.

Some of those you can't easily check from a script if at all other than by trying it out.

But for most of the more common cases above, there are ways. For instance:

- `[ -w dir ]` GNU `find -writable`, to check whether a directory is writable. Should also take care of read-only filesystems. Similar ones for readable / searchable.
- `ls -nd` (or various and incompatible implementations of `stat`), `find -user/-uid` to check file owner.
- `lsattr` to retrieve file flags.
- `mountpoint -q` to check if a file is a mountpoint. See also `findmnt`.

Putting it all together in a shell script and doing it reliably would be quite tricky though. Here's an attempt using `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
file=${1?}
export LC_ALL=C

name=$file:t parent=$file:h

die() {
  print -ru2 -- "$@"
  exit 1
}

# can't delete / . .. ""
[[ $name = (/|.|..|) ]] && die "Can't delete $file"

[[ -e $file || -L $file ]] || die "Can't tell whether $file exists"

[[ -w $parent ]] || die "Parent dir not writable"
[[ -x $parent ]] || die "Parent dir not searchable"

[[ -k $parent && ! -O $parent && ! -O $file ]] &&
  die "Parent has t bit, is not ours, nor is $file"

[[ $(lsattr -d -- $parent 2> /dev/null) = ????(i|?a)* ]] &&
  die "parent has a or i file flag"

mountpoint -q -- $file &&
  die "$file is a mount point"

# at this point, we should be able to delete non-directory files
[[ -L $file || ! -d $file ]] && exit 0

# same for empty readable dirs
[[ -r $file ]] && ()((! $#)) $file(NF) && exit 0

case $file in
  (/*) cd -P -- $file;;
  (*) cd -P -- ./$file;; # workaround for -, -1, +1, CDPATH...
esac 2> /dev/null || die "Can't cd into $file"

lsattr -Ra .//. 2> /dev/null |
  grep -Eq '^.{4}(i|.a).*//' &&
  die "Files with a and/or i file flags seen in $file"

zmodload zsh/system
{
  ERRNO=0
  non_empty_dirs=({.,**/*}(NDFoN))
  # error encountered while getting that list. Takes care of 
  # non-readable dirs or non-lstat()able mountpoints...
  (( ERRNO )) && {
    syserror -p "Error encountered while traversing $file: " $ERRNO
    exit 1
  }
}

for dir ($non_empty_dirs) {
  [[ -w $dir ]] || die "non-writable non-empty directory found"

  [[ -k $dir && ! -O $dir ]] && ()(($#)) $dir/*(ND^OY1) &&
    die "directory with t bit I don't own found with files I don't own inside"
}

mountpoints=(${(f)"$(findmnt -nlo target --submount -T .)"})
set -o extendedglob
for mount ($mountpoints) {
  # unescape the \xXX parts:
  mount=${mount//(#b)\\(x??)/${(#):-0$match[1]}}

  [[ $mount = $PWD/* ]] &&
    die "Mount point found under $file"
}

# probably deletable.
exit 0
```

To be used as:

```
if that-script "$some_dir_or_file"; then
  rm -rf -- "$some_dir_or_file"
  # and hope for the best
else
  echo probably not fully deletable
fi
```

It can still give false positives or false negatives in some corner cases. And of course between the time of check and the time of calling `rm`, many things could have changed in there.

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of Kaz's answer. Make a copy (`cp -a`) of the original tree, try to delete that copy, and if the deletion is successful then delete the original tree.

- -- : depending on the size of the tree, it can take longer, and more disk space
- ++ : the original tree remains untouched if it can not be atomically deleted

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 1 ] ; then
  echo "specify directory to remove"
  exit 1
fi

ar_src=$(realpath "$1")
ar_tmp=$(mktemp -d "$(dirname "$ar_src")/tmp-XXXXXX")

if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
  echo "unable to create temporary directory"
  exit 1
fi

if ! cp -a "$1" "$ar_tmp"; then
    echo "unable to copy"
    exit 1
fi

if rm -rf "$ar_tmp"; then
    rm -rf "$ar_src";
fi

exit 0
```

Execution :

```
$ ./atomic-rm2.sh d1/
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/testRMDIR/tmp-4sOBNS/d1/d2/f2': Permission denied

$ tree d1
d1
├── d2
│   └── f2
└── f1
```

Comment: ugh, that sounds like overkill. Also the issue that you might not be able to make the _copy_ in the first place, if you're missing read or access permission somewhere. You'd get a partial copy which you could probably remove, but might not be able to remove the original...

Comment: "that sounds like overkill" : not necessarily, it depends on the tree size. Like I said, the advantage is that the tree remains untouched if it can not be deleted
"you might not be able to make the copy" : good point, I added a test around the `cp -a`. The script works only if the whole tree is readable

Comment: It is not atomic. And does the `cp` maintain permissions || fail

Comment: Just because the copy is removable doesn't mean that the original is; it is not air tight. Also, just because a copy cannot be made, doesn't mean the original is not removable.  For instance, suppose that a file owned by user `bob` has `r--------` permissions, but is sitting in a writable directory that you own. You can delete that file, because you own the directory, but you cannot copy it because you cannot read it.

Comment: Yes. Good point !